# What's imagesDir & imagesPath in grunt-contrib-compass?

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using `grunt-contrib-compass`, in the settings, there are options like `imagesDir` and `imagesPath`. I'm just wondering what's that for, and how do I use it?

Comment: Why has this been negative commented? Isn't this a valid question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So apparently that options to be used in conjunction with `compass URL Helpers`. If you've specified `imagesDir` in your `Gruntfile.js`, you can call a `compass` function `images-url()` to generate the path to your images folder.

For example, this is how you specify the `Gruntfile.js`:

```
compass: {
  build: {
    options: {
      cssDir: './source/css/',
      sassDir: './source/css/',
      imagesDir: './source/images/',
      force: true,
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
    }
  }
}
```

And this is how you call the function from your `scss` file:

```
background-image: image-url( 'test.png' );
```

When you run the task, it'll be compiled into:

```
background-image: url('/./source/images/test.png');
```

Same thing applies for `fontsDir`, you just need to call different `compass` function `font-url()`. If you want to find more details, please follow the link http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much clearer it can get than what the docs have

```
[imagesDir](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#imagesdir)
Type: String
The directory where you keep your images.
```

and

```
[imagesPath](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#imagespath)
Type: String
Default: images
The directory where the images are kept. It is relative to the projectPath.
```

Maybe the definitions from [Compass's configuration reference](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/) would be helpful too?

```
images_dir: The directory where the images are kept. It is relative to the project_path. Defaults to "images".

images_path: The full path to where images are kept. Defaults to <project_path>/<images_dir>.
```

You can specify these just like any other option in your Gruntfile.js:

```
compass: {
  staging: {
    options: {
      imagesDir: 'images'
    }
  }
}
```

Note: these are typically used for compiling correct paths to images when you've used the compass [image-url helper](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I know the explanation is very clear, but I don't really know what to use that for in terms of compiling.