# cssDir vs cssPath in grunt-contrib-compass?

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass

In the optional configuration options for the Compass Grunt plugin (https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass), what is the difference between `cssDir` and `cssPath`?  Or do they both control the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, seems to be pretty well explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584382/whats-imagesdir-imagespath-in-grunt-contrib-compass?rq=1) – here's the jist:

- `cssDir` is strictly the name of the directory where your css files will be created. Defaults to `stylesheets`
- `cssPath` is the full *path* to that directory.  By default it is `<basePath>`/`<cssDir>`.

For most uses, simply setting the `cssDir` should be sufficient.